# Alert dialog EditText make the text/strings inputted masked with asterisk

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My current situation is when one of my item in recycler is deleted, it will prompt an alert dialog and it should be ask for a pin to open the item but then i can't mask all the strings being inputted in my alert dialog edittext.

Here is my current code and all the things that i have tried:

```
  final EditText passwordSales = new EditText(SalesHistoryActivity.this);
        passwordSales.setText("");
        passwordSales.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        passwordSales.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SalesHistoryActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Delete this sale?");
        alertDialog.setView(passwordSales);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
```

when i'm typing the password, it still show the text/string while typing.

Comment: Use a TextInputLayout instead of a EditText

Answer (score 0):

Set the transformation **after** the input type :

```
// setting a type may change the transformation method
passwordSales.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
// override the transformation
passwordSales.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SalesHistoryActivity.this).create();
```

By the way in your case `TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD` is probably better than `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`